# resolve-url-loader in webpack generated absolute local path not relative path

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-5, css-modules

I have a trouble with resolve-url-loader with webpack.

Loader produce absolute local path to file like `/Users/user/Projects/folder/my-app/distassets/Inter-Black.woff2` but not a `/assets/Inter-Black.woff2`. I'm understand that trouble in webpack configuration, but cannot find where it is exactly.

This is my webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
// const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const filepath = path.join(__dirname, "/dist");
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    path: filepath,
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "js/[name].js",
    assetModuleFilename: "assets/[name][ext]",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: "./dist",
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    hot: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },

      {
        test: /\.module\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: filepath,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 10"],
                  }),
                ],
              },
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "resolve-url-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        exclude: /\.module.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: filepath,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 10"],
                  }),
                ],
              },
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "resolve-url-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        sideEffects: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: { url: require.resolve("url/") },
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".scss"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
  ],
};
```

If I remove resolvve-url-loader I have an error that files cannot be found

UPD: basically, I found the solution - make filepath variable like `const filepath = path.join(__dirname, "../../../../../../");` but it's looks strange, isn't it? Maybe you could tell me a better solution?

Comment: Ok, so problem with ` /distassets/Inter-Black.woff2` was in filepath variable. Now it's just a `assets/... `